# How to send data from java servlet to android client

Tags: java, android, servlets

I am doing a simple application in android. The android application has a simple form and when I click the submit button from Android client the form values goes to servlet. Now I have a problem getting string values from servlet to Android client.

How can I send a string data from servlet? And how can I receive string data in Android client?

Comment: This is already been answered on your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5415220/problem-connecting-to-servlet-from-android-client

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a URLConnection to your servlet page and do it. Example for it: http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-download-fileimage-url-your-device

Answer (score 0):

Save the code below as CustomHttpClient.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.conn.params.ConnManagerParams;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;

public class CustomHttpClient {
    /** The time it takes for our client to timeout */
    public static final int HTTP_TIMEOUT = 30 * 1000; // milliseconds

    /** Single instance of our HttpClient */
    private static HttpClient mHttpClient;

    /**
     * Get our single instance of our HttpClient object.
     *
     * @return an HttpClient object with connection parameters set
     */
    private static HttpClient getHttpClient() {
        if (mHttpClient == null) {
            mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            final HttpParams params = mHttpClient.getParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
            ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
        }
        return mHttpClient;
    }

    /**
     * Performs an HTTP Post request to the specified url with the
     * specified parameters.
     *
     * @param url The web address to post the request to
     * @param postParameters The parameters to send via the request
     * @return The result of the request
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static String executeHttpPost(String url, ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader in = null;
        try {
            HttpClient client = getHttpClient();
            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
            UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);
            request.setEntity(formEntity);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
            String line = "";
            String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + NL);
            }
            in.close();

            String result = sb.toString();
            return result;
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Performs an HTTP GET request to the specified url.
     *
     * @param url The web address to post the request to
     * @return The result of the request
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static String executeHttpGet(String url) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader in = null;
        try {
            HttpClient client = getHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
            request.setURI(new URI(url));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
            String line = "";
            String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + NL);
            }
            in.close();

            String result = sb.toString();
            return result;
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now add the code where you want to make the client server communication

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",str2));

//here we are passing a variable str2 to the server. 
            String response = null;
try {

//address should be the http address of the server side code.
                    response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://www.xxx.xx/xxx.java", postParameters);
                      String res=response.toString();
                        res= res.replaceAll("\\s+","");


                    //res will be the string that you get from the server.
```