# What does this java line do?

Tags: java, android

```
response1 = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://gamesdsxd.com/appfiles/login.php", postParameters);
String res = response1.toString();
res = res.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
```

I'm wondering what \s+ does and what this replaceAll does and why it is needed.

Comment: Just click your way through the javadoc: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429330/how-to-send-data-from-java-servlet-to-android-client

Answer (score 4):

The `\s+` replaces all occurrences of a space `" "` with no space `""`.

For more help, see this link: [Removing Whitespace Between String.](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-remove-whitespace-between-string-java/)

Comment: Note that `\s` matches more than just ordinary space characters. It also matches tab characters, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what replaceAll will do with a small example:

```
String str = "This5is5testing5of5replaceAll";
        str = str.replaceAll("5", " ");
        System.out.println(str);
```

Here the output will be: `This is testing of replaceAll`

5 will be replaced by space everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

\s+ is a regular expression. It matches strings which consist of at least one white space character. \s is actually a meta character. Here it is removing white space.

Here is the replaceAll documentation.

replaceAll(String regex, String replacement) 
          Replaces each substring of this string that matches the given regular expression with the given replacement

Answer (score 0):

it replaces double spaces or more to no space. For example: "  " will transform into ""; "     " will transform into ""; but " " will still be equal to " ".